# Chrome/Firefox printing wide image/canvas to automatically tile across and down

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, printing

I have a CANVAS element that can be quite wide, depending on the actual content. For printing I'd like chrome/firefox to automatically tile the canvas image across multiple pages (horizontally first, then vertically).

The vertical tiling works fine, the print preview splits the canvas across two pages.

There doesn't seem to be any horizontal tiling at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default printing will always cut the canvas off when it is too wide. No getting around that.

However...

Replacing the original canvas with small vertical slices of the original canvas allows the browser to page break at roughly the correct location.