# How to print a large canvas across multiple page widths in browser?

Tags: html, css, canvas, browser

My application needs to print out an arbitrarily large canvas that can span multiple page width and height widths.

There was a similar question some time back [where it was claimed the browser won't print to multiple page widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706977/chrome-firefox-printing-wide-image-canvas-to-automatically-tile-across-and-down).

Since this was a while back I am wondering if it is still true. Also, what strategies are available to print out a large canvas without splitting it up?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");

function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //   //  LEVER

  //plane
  context.fillStyle = '#aaa';
  context.fillRect(25, 90, 2500, 400);


}

$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_a();

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <div class="printOnly Aligner-item--bottom"> Print Only</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: chrome does support [`@page{size:4050px 2550px;}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) which will make your page big enough for your canvas to fit. FF doesn't... https://jsfiddle.net/3ngqg3x2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem that browsers will split up a large canvas into multiple pages. I tested on MacOS Sierra using latest chrome and safari browsers.

A possible approach for printing a canvas is to first transform it to a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) containing a representation of the image using `canvas.toDataURL()`. You can then manipulate the image dimensions prior to printing.

```
"<img src='" + canvas.toDataURL() + "' height='500px' width='500px' />'"
```

In the following example, the large `4500px` by `4500px` `canvas` is translated into an `img` and placed inside an `iframe`, used for printing. You can probably append the image to the original document and than print that specific element, but the `iframe` may be more flexible to handle print output. You can manipulate the `img` dimensions according to your requirements and print a scaled representation of the canvas. Note that I hardcoded the `width` and `height` of the image but this can be calculated and changed as needed for printing.

Due to iframe cross-origin restrictions, the code snippet below will not work here, but it does work on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/52cmo255/).

The scaled `500px` by `500px` image representing the canvas fits on one page when printed.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");

function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //   //  LEVER

  //plane
  context.fillStyle = '#aaa';
  context.fillRect(25, 90, 4500, 4500);
}

print = function() {
 window.frames["myFrame"].focus();
 window.frames["myFrame"].print();
}

function setupPrintFrame() {
 $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">').appendTo("body").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append("<img src='" + canvas.toDataURL() + "' height='500px' width='500px' />'");
    },50);
 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_a();
 setupPrintFrame();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly, #myFrame {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="print()" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <canvas height="4500px" width="4500px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <div class="printOnly Aligner-item--bottom"> Print Only</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use the jsfiddle link provided. [jsfiddle link]:(https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/52cmo255/).

Comment: I want this to work, but it doesn't work at all in IE and appears truncated in chrome. I recreated your work in a pen: https://codepen.io/mjankowski/pen/bryWGM

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely work. I tested your codepen successfully with Windows 10 (Chrome), MacOS Sierra (Chrome and Safari). On IE11, the problem seems to be in your `@media -ms-high-contrast` rule. I removed this rule in the following pen [https://codepen.io/jfeferman/pen/eEaWxJ](https://codepen.io/jfeferman/pen/eEaWxJ) and IE11 worked but with a large canvas size. In IE11, use `msToBlob()` instead of `toDataURL()` according to this post [Download canvas to image in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860633/download-canvas-to-image-in-ie-using-javascript).

Comment: More info: tested successfully on Windows 10, Edge browser. `toDataURL() ` works as expected and renders the small 500x500 image on print. IE11, however, seems problematic and would require more investigation.

Comment: Thank you for these edits. I'm taking a look into them.

Comment: Well, I'll keep looking at this approach. It doesn't spread the image out over multiple pages but shrinks the image down to where it will assuredly fit on one page. I need multiple page widths.

Comment: Yes, that is understood. You can manipulate the image dimensions to fit on one page or spread it out over several pages. The trick here is that this approach transforms an unmanageable canvas to an image that can be manipulated prior to printing.

Comment: Awarded to this answer because it comes closest to providing a solution. After more experimentation I think the original goal of printing out a canvas image over multiple pages is not possible right now. The only workable solution seems to be to come up with a strategy to shrink the image to a printable page width.

Answer (score 3):

```
@media print {  
  @page {
    size: 297mm 210mm; /* landscape */
    /* you can also specify margins here: */
    margin: 25mm;
    margin-right: 45mm; /* for compatibility with both A4 and Letter */
  }
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //   //  LEVER
  //plane
  context.fillStyle = '#aaa';
  context.fillRect(25, 90, 2500, 400);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_a();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}
.printOnly {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
 @page {
    size: 297mm 210mm; /* landscape */
    /* you can also specify margins here: */
    margin: 25mm;
    margin-right: 45mm; /* for compatibility with both A4 and Letter */
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
        height: 100%;
    
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <div class="printOnly Aligner-item--bottom"> Print Only</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does show a the printout across multiple vertical pages. However, I need to figure out how to print across multiple page widths. How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this fiddle in both browsers firefox and chrome using a localhost environment and it worked within both. Here is the [original js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ngqg3x2)

And here is the html I tested

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");

function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //   //  LEVER

  //plane
  context.fillStyle = '#aaa';
  context.fillRect(25, 90, 2500, 400);


}

$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_a();

});
```

```css
div.sizePage {
  color: #333;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
            height: 100%;
    
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
            height: 100%;
    
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <div class="printOnly Aligner-item--bottom"> Print Only</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I thinks it's safe to say that it is supported in both browsers now.

I am using the most recent update on both browsers.

Comment: This shrinks the image. I need to preserve the image size and print across multiple page widths.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    function draw_a() {
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     context.fillStyle   = '#aaa';
     context.fillRect  (25, 90, 2500, 400);
    } 
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      draw_a();
    });
```

```css
@page Section1 {
    size:8.27in 11.69in; 
    margin:0; 
    mso-header-margin:0; 
    mso-footer-margin:0; 
    mso-paper-source:0;
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
  <div class="myDivToPrint">
    <div class="Aligner-item">
      <canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1" style="border: solid 10px #000;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 31,
  "colno": 5

Comment: Pulled this out into codepen.io and it prints vertically but does not show the width I need.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to handle this problem using plain CSS styles.
I recommend to clone element to print multiple times (in this case), put copies after each other and make them "print only" using CSS. Additionally, canvas can't be just cloned - it needs to be redrawn for each copy.

Number of copies depends on the element and page widths.
Default page width is 210mm, it can be converted to px ([Pixel to Centimeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341930/pixel-to-centimeter)) and compared to the element's width.

When we have page width in pixels, we can set negative left margin for each copy respectively. Having that, entire canvas will be "divided" into columns and printed from top to bottom.

In order to have each copy printed starting from the new page, simple use this CSS rule:

```
page-break-before: always;
```

There is a lot of hardcoded things, however I think that you could use it to build a generic solution for your problem.

```js
var divide = function(selector, pageWidth) {
  var elementToDivide = document.querySelector(selector);
  var widthPx = elementToDivide.offsetWidth;
  var pageWidthPx = pageWidth * 3.7795;

  for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(widthPx/pageWidthPx); i++) {
    var clone = elementToDivide.cloneNode(true);
    elementToDivide.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

    draw_a(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"))
    clone.style.marginLeft = "-" + (pageWidthPx * i) + "px";
    clone.className += " printOnly";
  }
}

var standardPrint = window.print;

window.print = function() {
  if (!window.pagesDivided) {
    divide(".myDivToPrint", 210);
    window.pagesDivided = true;
  }
  standardPrint();
};

function draw(canvas) {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 4000, 2500);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "red");

  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fillRect(25, 25, 4000, 2500);
}

function draw_a(elem) {
  if (elem.length != null && elem.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      draw(elem[i]);
    }
  } else {
    draw(elem);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  draw_a(document.getElementById("canvas1"));
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 5px dashed;
}
.printOnly {
  display: none;
}
.myDivToPrint { 
  float: left;
}
@media print {
 @page {
    size: 297mm 210mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    margin-right: 0mm;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    page-break-before: always;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <div class="printOnly Aligner-item--bottom"> Print Only</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this was the technically most 'correct' answer. This approach shows the most promise to print a canvas element over multiple pages. However, I didn't award it the bounty because the accepted answer provided a workable alternative. It was really close. If I could have split the bounty I would have.